# How to use save page as... with react-router

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

Is it possible to save page a webapp using react-router/react/redux for offline viewing.

The issue is saving a page and all the contents are in the save folder and htm file.
When I open the htm file the url is

file:///Users//Downloads/test.htm

And react router does not see this as a valid route.

Are there any alternatives or ways of disabling react-router when saving?

Thanks!